# Automating email sending by using telnet & FTP on OS X CLI

Tags: macos, command-line, email, smtp, telnet

Running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cvs_domain=abc.com
cvs_mail_server=mail.${cvs_domain}
cvs_port=25
telnet $cvs_mail_server $cvs_port<<_EOF_
EHLO $cvs_domain
MAIL FROM:my_mail@abc.com
RCPT TO:my_mail@abc.com
DATA
Subject:Test!

Don't panic. This is only a test.
.
QUIT
_EOF_
```

fails with a `Connection closed by host` message, right after the server replying with the escape character, and before serving the `220` message.

Running the corresponding sequence in interactive mode (of course, without the "here-doc") accomplishes my goal.

I suspect "feeding" the command lines to the server doesn't happen exactly as expected at the other end of the line.

Is my assumption correct? Is there a way to mitigate this problem?

Comment: I suggest you watch what is going on in wireshark

Comment: you write "without the "here-doc"  " <-- what? those words don;t occur anywhere

Comment: @barlop This should've crossed my mind! Excellent idea (Wireshark). As for the "here-doc", I was referring to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to script an interactive command-line tool, the typical solution is to use `expect(1)`.

Comment: Even though this is the elegant answer, I was able to find a way around this issue by applying the second technique (braced expressions) mentioned by `thiton` in his answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts .  A pure Bash solution may be preferable under certain scenarios.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm thorough, I also introduced delays (`sleep 1`) between my commands. "Here-doc" notation no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of the completeness, I am posting here the full "ugly-but-it-works" solution (with the amends that, in its final form, it sends emails to more people, as well as provides an attachment):

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
working_dir=$(pwd)  # switching to the folder this script has been started from

cvs_domain=mail.org
cvs_mail_server=mail.${cvs_domain}
cvs_port=25
cvs_sender=me@mail.org
cvs_recipients=(me@mail.org me@mail.com)
cvs_delimiter=-----nEXt_paRt_frontier!!VSFCDVGGERHERZZ@$%^zzz---  # MIME multi-part delimiter, do not change

{ echo HELO $cvs_domain; sleep 1
  # set up the email (sender, receivers): 
  echo MAIL FROM:$cvs_sender; sleep 1
  for r in ${cvs_recipients[@]}; do
    echo RCPT TO:$r; sleep 1
  done
  echo DATA; sleep 1
  echo From:$cvs_sender; sleep 1
  for r in ${cvs_recipients[@]}; do
    echo To:$r; sleep 1
  done
  echo Subject:Test for build; sleep 1
  # build the mail structure, according to the MIME standard:
  echo MIME-Version: 1.0; sleep 1
  echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$cvs_delimiter\""; sleep 1
  echo --${cvs_delimiter}; sleep 1
  echo Content-Type: text/plain; sleep 1
  echo; sleep 1
  echo Don\'t panic. This is only a test.; sleep 1
  echo; sleep 1
  echo --${cvs_delimiter}; sleep 1
  echo "Content-Type: text/plain; name=\"test.txt\""; sleep 1
  echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.txt\""; sleep 1
  echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"; sleep 1
  echo; sleep 1
  encoded_file=$( base64 ./change.log )  # encoding the contents of the file, according to the declaration above
  echo "$encoded_file"; sleep 1
  echo; sleep 1  
  echo --${cvs_delimiter}; sleep 1 
  echo .; sleep 1
  echo QUIT
  sleep 1; } | telnet $cvs_mail_server $cvs_port
```

One may choose to fiddle with the delays. And, for (what I think may be) a more robust solution, I would go with `expect(1)`.